# How to change closeMenuOnSelect value on event in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to close the `Select` dropdown when the limit of selected items is reached.

The following is not working:

```
handleSearch = selectedOption => {
    const closeMenuOnSelect = selectedOption.length >= 3;
    this.setState({ closeMenuOnSelect }, () => this.updateSelect());
}

updateSelect = () => {
    console.log(this.state.closeMenuOnSelect); // the state is getting updated but it does not have the effect on the `closeMenuOnSelect` property
}
```

And the component:

```
<Select className='react-select-container'
                            isMulti
                            closeMenuOnSelect={this.state.closeMenuOnSelect}
                            options={this.state.locations}
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleSearch(e)} />
```

It doesn't need to on event. I just want the menu to remain open and when the limit of selected options is reached I want to close it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop "menuIsOpen" in React Select and by using it you can control the open or close of dropDown

```
const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
<Select className='react-select-container'
        isMulti
        options={this.state.locations}
        onChange={(e) => this.handleSearch(e)}
        menuIsOpen={showMenu}
        onBlur={() => setShowMenu(false)}
        blurInputOnSelect
/>
```

So now you can call setShowMenu(true) / setShowMenu(false) to show or hide the select menu as per your need.

Comment: Your solution is incomplete. And how does the `closeMenuOnSelect` fits into it? @rashi

Comment: Hi I have updated the answer Please try and let me know if it still not works